# 508/Accessibility Rules for (1) Links Must Have Discernible Text, (2) Empty Table Cells (Axe Plugin)

Tags: html, css, accessibility, section508

I'm running the [Axe plugin](https://www.deque.com/axe/) to ensure the validity and 508 accessibility of my app, and some of the violations reported are too restrictive and I don't know how to fix them because they are valid cases:

**1. "Links must have discernible text"**

In reference to a Tooltip link which isn't supposed to have any text. It's a graphic and must exist on the page by itself. In general, how do you handle textless links which are very common?

`<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="This is a tooltip icon by itself">`

**2. All th elements and elements with role=columnheader/rowheader must have data cells they describe**

*"We are not sure this is an issue, because:
Table data cells are missing or empty"*

I have a table where the last column is "Actions" that only contains graphic icons, no text; e.g. there's a View button, Edit button, and Delete button. The column is structured as

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit"> 
           <i class="fa fa-pencil" alt="Edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete">
           <i class="fa fa-trash" alt="Delete"></i>
        </a>
     </td>
```

It's the lack of inner-HTML text that triggers Axe's "Empty Cell" violation. Do I just ignore it? This is a common scenario, I don't want to be hit by it constantly.

Comment: Put the proper text in there, and hide it from non-screenreader users … https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: No, there should be no text there in principle. I shouldn't distort a clean DOM just to satisfy screen readers. There is no "proper" text when the elements are *supposed* to be empty.

Comment: _“when the elements are supposed to be empty”_ - just because you think replacing actual link text with a fancy icon was the right way to do things, doesn’t actually make it so.

Comment: If you're saying that an empty table cell (forget about icons, just an empty cell) should be a problem for screen readers, I fundamentally disagree with that assumption.

Comment: Well why is it there in the first place, if it has absolutely no content?

Comment: There could be lots of reasons why. Not everything has a value in that row/column, for whatever reason, and that emptiness is intentional, for example.

Comment: Disable _all_ CSS, and try to use your page/app with the rendering you get with the pure HTML. If you can not easily manage that … then you didn’t do things right in the first place ;-)

Comment: Imagine if you are using a screenreader and you can't physically see the site. What would make sense for you to hear? Perhaps something generic like "spacer" or "blank"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your icons, graphics, buttons, or links execute some action you need to provide some text alternative to screen readers that describes the action taken by the link.

Either add an `aria-label` attribute to the links describing their purpose, or place a span tag with descriptive text within the link that is hidden from sight using CSS but will be accessible to screen readers.

Additionally your usage of the `alt` attribute on your `i` elements is incorrect. You should hide the icon using `aria-hidden="true"`, and provide a text alternative via another element.

There is nothing inherently wrong with having an empty `td` element within a table as the `td` element has the roll of cell and elements of the roll cell do not require an accessible name. If the cell contains content such as an icon you would want to make sure that an accessible alternative is provided, or if the content is strictly decorative appropriate action is taken.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#cell

An issue would arise if you had an empty `th` element as it would have a role of either rowheader or columnheader, and an accessible name is required for both.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#columnheader

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#rowheader

**Helpful information for using icons:** https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Icon_Font_with_an_On-Screen_Text_Alternative

**Information on describing the purpose of a link:** https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-refs.html#navigation-mechanisms-refs-techniques-head

**Hiding content from sighted users:**
https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: Thanks, the link/icon went away; what about general empty Table cells (Part 2 of my question)? Even without any icons, I sometimes have empty TD cells (nothing in them) and that triggers a violation from Axe.

Comment: @geneb. I have expanded the answer to address your question about table cells. Note that it's possible your scanning tool is indicating a false positive, and you will need to use your best judgement based off the guidelines in the answer.